# Varying menus by page meteor kitchen

Tags: meteor, meteor-kitchen

I've been using [Meteor Kitchen](http://www.meteorkitchen.com/applications) to develop the structure of my site - pages, logins etc., and on the whole it's been very productive.  However I would like the some of the items in the menu to vary by page, rather than be consistent throughout the site.  I can vary the menus by zone (Public, Private, Free), and by user type, but I haven't figured out how to vary them by page (route). How is that done?

I'm looking for information about how to use the code generation tool, rather than specific code advice.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please add code snippets and screenshot, so we can understand what you mean exactly. Maybe have a look at this: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Meteor Kitchen is a code generator - it produces a json file that gets turned into code by the command line interface. This is really a question about using the web tool to produce the code, rather than a question about the code it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu system is most likely expressed as HTML inside a *blaze template*. The most basic approach is to wrap the elements in your menus with `{{#if }}` blocks driven by whatever conditions are necessary to show/hide items.

You can also define menus as separate templates and swap the whole thing in:

```
{{#if condition1}}
  {{> menu1}}
{{else}}
  {{> menu2}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the author, Petar Korponaić, the "main idea behind Meteor Kitchen is to build as much code as possible in the beginning."  It looks like I've reached that point - the end of the beginning - so I now need to switch to hand-coding, which makes Michel Floyd's response, to use the Spacebars {{#if }} blocks in the template, the appropriate response.